# Ajax request isn't working in cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to do an ajax request in cakephp.
My submit is `#enviar`. My action is `pages/contato`.

This is my ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#enviar').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
        url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'contato')); ?>",
        })
    })
});
```

I change the $.ajax for a simple `alert()` and when i click submit this works.
Where is my problem?

Comment: at the end of `url`, change `? >` to `?>`. ALso, define a `success:` to see if something is returning.

Comment: sorry. My code is `?>` i wrote wrong. About the `sucess:` returning nothing

Comment: what does `<?php echo Router::url..` evaluate to ?

Comment: what error is thrown in console

Comment: <h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /teste/&lt;
on this server.</p>

Comment: `/teste/&lt;` is not a valid url, what was the expected url

Comment: `teste/pages/contato` is the correct url

Comment: @IgorMartins: possibly you haven't added your function in $this->Auth->allow. Now you are trying to access it without logging in. Try adding it to allow and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Better change the url, in your ajax function :-

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
    url:"http://localhost/teste/pages/contato"
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But, i want to to it with a cakephp controller router for do not put the entire url.

Comment: @IgorMartins Look for that you just need to use controller_name/function_name .But the problem wit this is that it always wont work. Even i faced a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Add an .htaccess file to the working directory with the following code:

```
allow from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Html helper and an absolute path?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "<?=$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'pages',
                                    'action' => 'contato'),
                              true);?>"
});
```